# While printing how to snip space from the end of the list

Tags: python

Hi i need to remove a white space at the end of each line while printing to a file from a list.

Here is my code

```
lst =[['Apple',330.0, 2.2 ,'Kg'],['banana',22,330.0, 2.2 ,'Kg']]
g = open('Receipt.txt', 'w')
l=0
p=''
for i in lst:
    for j in range(len(lst[l])):
        print(lst[l][j],end=' ',file=g)
    l += 1
g.close()
```

need output in file like this:

```
Apple 330.0 2.2 Kg
banana 22 330.0 2.2 Kg
```

I have used this for loop to write all the indexes in single line with help of end = ' ' but unfortunately its creating a space at the end of each line. Which is a issue for me.

How can we add a condition that if lst index reaches -1 which is last index 'kg' it shouldn't include space in that one.

Simplest solution needed please

Comment: Why do you use two for loops? Why don't you just write each sublist at once in one line?

Comment: I'd suggest using better variable names than `g` (a file io object), `i` (a list of strings), `j` and `l` (integers); especially `l` since it looks like `1`. Use explicit ones that say what they are `file`, `sublst`, `index` (`l` is unneeded).

Comment: @GHTMitchell i know. Its just a sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print the line all at once, using `' '` as a separator

```
lst =[['Apple',330.0, 2.2 ,'Kg'],['banana',22,330.0, 2.2 ,'Kg']]
with open('Receipt.txt', 'w+') as g:
    for i in lst:
        print(*i, sep=' ', file=g)
```

makes the file

```
Apple 330.0 2.2 Kg
banana 22 330.0 2.2 Kg
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain a bit how this line is working  print(*i, sep=' ', file=g)

Comment: `*i` unpacks the list `i`.  So if `i = [1, 2, 3]`, `print(*i)` is the same as `print(1, 2, 3)`.  You can read that line as "print the contents of `i`, separated by `' '` to file `g`"

Comment: An alternative: `print(" ".join(str(itm) for itm in i), file=g)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's give you another solution, quite close to the @PatrickHaugh's one, but without using the unpacking operator. I use:

- `with ... as ...` statements to properly open and close the file
- a `for` loop to iterate over the list and manage each sublist one by one
- `map(str, i)` to convert each element of the sublist `i` into `str`type
- `' '.join(...)` to convert the sublist into a string with elements separated by a blank space, with no blank space at the end

Here is the code:

```
lst =[['Apple',330.0, 2.2 ,'Kg'],['banana',22,330.0, 2.2 ,'Kg']]
with open('Receipt.txt', 'w+') as g:
    for i in lst:
        print(' '.join(map(str,i)), file=g)
```